# Center logo displayed with background image

Tags: html, css, background

I'm creating a header that contains only the logo. I am displaying this logo as a DIV with a background image as opposed to as an image. The image is fine on desktop and has a left margin of 2vh. I've tried to center it on mobile but for some reason it isn't working.

```css
.logoholder {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
    height: 8vh;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
    margin-left: 2vh;
    background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.logo {
    height: 8vh;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png");
    background-position: center
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="logoholder">
<a href="/">
<div class="logo">
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: It's an SVG so should just scale, it's only the media query with the issue. Only issue is that it won't center.

Comment: We'll need *something* for testing unless someone can just figure it out by looking at the css.

Comment: I'll add something, apologies.

Comment: Someone might be able to figure it out.

Comment: Added the google logo for ease, sizing is fine so doesn't need to be modified. Just positioning of the logo is an issue for some reason. (center it)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is reason for doing this but there probably is not good justification in terms of how css actually works. You will likely achieve better results by using an actual image and absolutely positioning it in the center of the div and just layering any additional content on top. This will allow you to size the image anyway you want and maintiain any position you want.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to being a width issue of the DIV. I just need the width to be correct in terms of the DIV that the logo is in.

Comment: Can you provide an image of your screen? That would probably help. Using "vh" for you margin  and height is probably the problem. Having a height of 8vh would hypothetically make your div 8x the height of your viewport. Adding vh for margin would only exacerbate that problem and giveyou completely unpredictable results.

Comment: I've changed it and just sized an image like I usually would. It's less complicated with images that don't need to be centered on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This makes image downloading easier for users but is the way I'd usually align a logo.

```css
.logo {
    height: 8vh;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
    margin-left: 2vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.logo {
    height: 8vh;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
}
```

```html
<a href="/"><img class="logo" src="./logo.svg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-position` and `background-size` CSS properties to position and resize the image. Try the below code.

```css
.logoholder {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  height: 8vh;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  margin-left: 2vh;
  background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .logo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logoholder">
  <a href="/">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```